# How To Make Bootstrap Modal Appear After Some Time Interval

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

```
 <script>
        
          {% comment %} $('.btnc').click('load',function(){
            setTimeout(function () { 
                $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show')
             },3000)
        })
         {% endcomment %}
  {% comment %} 
         $(".btnc").click(function(){
          $(this).data('clicked', true);
      });
  
      if($('.btnc').data('clicked')) {
        alert('yes');
    } {% endcomment %}
  
  
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal();
  }, 20000);
  
  
  
        </script>



 <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-10 col-lg-12">

                <form method = "post" action = "">

                  {% csrf_token %}

      <div class="mx-auto mb-5 mt-5 p-5 ipt">
        <h1 class="text-center text-lowercase">Enter The URL</h1>
  
          <p class="text-center text-lowercase btxt">Check the online reputation/safety of a website.</p>
          <p class="text-center text-lowercase btxt">Free scanner to detect phishing & fraudulent sites in real-time</p>
        <!-- </div> -->
        <!-- <div class="col-lg-6">   -->
          <div class="input-group">

          <!-- <div class="input-group mb-3 ipbx"> -->
          <!-- <div class="input-group mb-3"> -->
  
            <div class="ml-auto mt-5  col-xs-4">

              <input type="text" class="form-control iptxt" name="urlinfo" style="border-radius: 5px;" placeholder="enter url" aria-label="User's URL" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" />
            </div>
              <div class="input-group-append mt-5 mr-auto">
                  <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btnc">CHECK</button> -->
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btnc" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                  
                  {% comment %} </input> {% endcomment %}
              </div>
            
              
              <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color:black;">{{url}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;">
          {% comment %} <h1>HELOO</h1> {% endcomment %}
          {{rslt}}
          {% comment %} {% if {{rslt}} == Null %}
            <h1>Hello</h1>
          {% endif %} {% endcomment %}

          {% comment %} {% if  %}{% endif %} {% endcomment %}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
          </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
  <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
  </div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Already Tried This

With Load It Load With Windows Loaded But I Need Something Like It Should Take 5-10 Seconds After The Button Is Preesed
Also With window.load The Close Button Wont Work
I Am Creating Website That Detect Phisng Or Not For That Reason I Want To Make SOme Time Delay So My Output Will Get Genreted From Python File

Answer (score 0):

Put setTimeout function into $(document).ready()

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function() {
         $('#myModal').modal('show'); // set command for show 
      }, 20000);
 });
```

That's a working sample;

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#MyModal").modal("show");
  },2000);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p> wait 2 seconds for modal pop-up! </p>
 
 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">{{url}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {% comment %} <h1>HELOO</h1> {% endcomment %}
          {{rslt}}
          {% comment %} {% if {{rslt}} == Null %}
            <h1>Hello</h1>
          {% endif %} {% endcomment %}

          {% comment %} {% if  %}{% endif %} {% endcomment %}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not Working Serhat

Comment: Be sure; all of neccessery external libraries are ok, all of html tag ids are unique and case sensitive, jquery codes must be located at the end of the page.